# How to get the IP address of the device in WIFI DIRECT?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am working on an application where i am connecting two devices over wifi direct.Now,I have only the IP address of the groupowner , so i am only able to send data to group owner.But i want to send data both ways. so ,i need the IP address of client also.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any relative Code ( + error log ) ?